# How can I send an email address and current url

Tags: javascript, mailto

How can I send the current URL to specific email address.

Tried this but it's opening two emails:

```html
<a href="mailto:recruit@jnpgroup.co.uk" onclick="javascript:window.location='mailto:?subject=Website Job Application&body=Website Job URL: ' + window.location;">Click here to apply by e-mail</a>
```

Hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will open 2 emails

**First:)**
 Due to the `href` attribute that browser requests when clicked automatically.

**Second:)**
 Due to the `onClick` javascript event that your are processing.

**FIX:**  Chose any one from the above.